# Find multiple values in square brackets (and preceding text) with JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string like this:

```
"fieldNameA[fieldValueA] fieldNameB[fieldValueB] fieldNameC[fieldValueC]"
```

I'm looking for a regular expression (or two) that will allow me to construct a set of key value pairs e.g.

```
fieldNameA : "fieldValueA"
fieldNameB : "fieldValueB"
fieldNameC : "fieldValueC"
```

- Values will always be in square brackets.
- Square brackets will always be preceded by the field name
- Field names could vary in length

I tried something like:

```
const reg = new RegExp("fieldNameA|fieldNameB|fieldNameC\[(.*?)\]", "gi");
const matches = reg.exec(query);
```

But this doesn't work. I just get an array with one value: "fieldNameA"

Comment: You can use this regex [`/(\w+)\[([^\]]+)\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/ejTxpP/1)

Comment: You may try with `var reg = /(fieldNameA|fieldNameB|fieldNameC)\[(.*?)\]/gi` - if the names are hardcoded. Then use `while(m=reg.exec(query)) { /*do stuff*/ }`. If names are not fixed, you may use `\w+` as in the other suggestion.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/eqno1nu7/

Comment: thanks, both of these are great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following solution:

```js
var query = "fieldNameA[fieldValueA] fieldNameB[fieldValueB] fieldNameC[fieldValueC]";
var matches = {}, m;
var reg = /(\w+)\[(.*?)]/gi;
while(m=reg.exec(query)) { 
  matches[m[1]] = m[2];
}
console.log(matches);
```

You need to use a regex literal, or `"\["` will turn into `"["` and will no longer match a literal `[`.

Also, to match all occurrences, you need to run a `RegExp#exec` in a loop.

**Pattern details**:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars (if you want to match an identifier that cannot start with a digit, replace with `[_a-zA-Z]\w*`)
- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars (if you need to match any char but `]`, use `[^\]]*`)
- `]` - a literal `]` char.